# JS-Ctypes on Firefox OS

Tags: firefox-os, jsctypes

I had used js-ctypes on Firefox OS app long ago but I dont seem to be able to do it now. I can't even use `Components`, has js-ctypes been disallowed form FxOS apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Components object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_Bindings/Components_object) you're referring to is only available to Firefox Add-ons or Gecko/XUL.  Apps on Firefox OS are 100% HTML5, CSS3, and ECMAScript5.  The only additional APIs are [lower level hardware access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/App_permissions) that we're working to standardize.

If you're looking to work with C or C++ code in the browser, the preferred way is to use [Emscripten](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/) to cross compile it to JS.  Emscripten does have its limitation, and it depends on what you're trying to do.

If you're simply trying to work with data backed by a Typed Array, in the future we will have [Typed Objects](https://github.com/dslomov/typed-objects-es7) in ES7, which more usable than [the current story](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays#Working_with_complex_data_structures).

Comment: Aw darn, ok thnkas @Nick, I had some linux libraries i want to use, some native, and some my own .so files :(

Comment: @Noitidart The .so files would have to be cross compiled to run on ARM anyways (betting you're not developing on an ARM host).  If you have access to the source of the shared libs, you could cross compile those to JS with Emscripten, then call into them.